# When does it become necessary to create a new community for a specific game?

Tags: discussion

As many games grow (more specifically, pokemon go) the content of arqade has become mostly pokemon-go based. Should we create a new community for just those games? Or should we wait for the popularity of those games to die down?

Comment: If you're going to downvote my post, please leave a comment saying in what ways I can improve my question, or just edit it.

Comment: Votes work different on meta sites. Votes show (dis)agreement with the topic at hand. There's no reputation applied to votes here either. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen how many Minecraft questions we have? We have 7047 and counting, and yet, every time someone proposes a SE site dedicated to Minecraft in A51, it gets closed as a duplicate of the Arqade. We don't need to create a separate site to handle questions for a specific game. We have plenty of active members and high rep members, plus an awesome group of mods to deal with the traffic. All creating a new SE site for a specific game will do is draw traffic away from here to another site, and we don't want to have sites competing for traffic in the same scope and community.

**TLDR** We don't need to create new sites dedicated to super popular games.

Comment: Plus it's way too early to tell if the Pokemon GO questions are even going to remain so popular. In a few months we could be just getting a few questions a week, which isn't enough to sustain a site.

Comment: @Wipqozn quite true.

Comment: @Wipqozn you optimist. I give the Pokemon Go trend 4 weeks to die.

Comment: @Wipqozn You're absolutely right. The influx of Overwatch questions has died down significantly, albeit with more in-depth and tactics-based questions taking their place.

Answer (score 2):

Never.

Filtering by game tag works very well for this purpose. And if you're really annoyed by the currently popular game, just ignore the tag.

New SE sites are created when the topic doesn't entirely fit into an existing site. They're usually not created for complete subsets of existing sites. Even in cases where it might look like this, e.g. the Drupal site is very similar to the Drupal tag on Stack Overflow, there are questions that are accepted on Drupal that would not fit to SO. The new site is not a complete subset, only a partial one.

I don't see any compelling reason to split off any particular game from this site.

Comment: I agree. When looking at other SE sites, they tend to cover broad topics (ex. Arqade for all games, Superuser for general PC things, etc). Having such a specific topic like Minecraft or PokemonGo takes away the nature of the more broad sites, and could lead to a massive amount of SEs for one specific game.

Answer (score 0):

You already have detailed answers for why we don't split off games into new sites.

The only justification I can give with going ahead with a new site is when the questions for a game go beyond just playing the game.

Minecraft appears to span multiple sites.  I have seen questions across several sites:

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) - 1,305 questions regarding programming mods
[Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) - 170 questions regarding design/dev of Minecraft features
[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/minecraft/info) - Thousands across a large number of tags that mostly deal with playing

As you can see, Minecraft features across at least 3 StackExchange sites.  For a user asking something in the realms of making mods or programming command blocks, or even server configuration, there is a probably something lost putting this into one specific site.  Do Minecraft experts actively watch the tags across multiple sites?

I'm sure there is a strong argument for keeping things the way they are.  To be fair, the on-topic/off-topic nature of Minecraft questions across all 3 sites has had plenty of community discussions.

However, I'm sure there are some common or useful questions that don't fit into any site.  For example, no site wants to deal with crashes when a mod has been installed (this is a frequent question to this site).

I believe there have been numerous attempts to get Minecraft its own site, but they seem to have failed:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/100612/minecraft-modding