# When should the Spam flag be used?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

Right now the spam tag is labeled as

> Exsits only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

and in the author's affiliation it says

> "The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam..." and "Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much."

But recently I flagged a post for spam advertising a speedrunning website but the flag got denied and instead the post was removed for being off-topic. In the situation described with the flags description, the spam flag seems like it would fit perfectly here.

In what situation should the spam flag be used?

Comment: In addition to the Help Center page you linked, I would encourage you to read the [FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/525551) for spam flags. While I can't speak to the individual decision to decline your flag as I can't see the post, I will say that it's generally best practice to try "nicer" methods of correction first before slamming a user with a red flag. This should be the procedure for all but the most blatant of posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### When should the Spam flag be used?

When you think something is Spam.

It's a judgement call. Spam flags are relevant when someone posts a wildly irrelevant question or answer promoting a product to the site, or an answer that seems relevant to the question on the surface, but contains unrelated product links or information. For example on the latter:

[image: Spam answer]

Note that a successful spam vote is a serious mark against an account and severely limits what that account can do.

---

The question you flagged was a little promotional, but ultimately it was internal to Stack Exchange. It discusses an SE network feature - creating a new Stack Exchange site based on a sub-section of gaming - something we've covered before on meta with regards to Minecraft: [When does it become necessary to create a new community for a specific game?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11824/28182).

Even if your flag was declined, the flag alerted the mods to the post and appropriate actions were taken (migration to meta and deletion off the main site).

Also note: not all answers that contain product or purchase links are spam. If the product is a relevant solution to the question at hand and the author discloses their affiliation (or lack thereof), it's ok. As an example, [here's an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/305107/28182) I provided that links to a site to purchase replacement parts (and disclosed my lack of affiliation).

Comment: Is it me or there isn't many post posted by spam bot? I see more often spam post on AU

Comment: @damadam - There are a lot of mechanisms in place to detect and stop spam pretty quickly these days - including a community-led effort called Charcoal/[Smoke Detector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/179041) - spam lasts no longer than 2-3 minutes tops on our site :)